# MicroStrategy CREATE REPORT statement syntax

Tags: dynamic, report, microstrategy

Trying to create a bunch of MicroStrategy reports via code (instead of manually going through the GUI).  Does anyone have a working CREATE REPORT statement?

Here's an example of a working CREATE ATTRIBUTE statement:

```
CREATE ATTRIBUTE "attrib1" DESCRIPTION "attrib1" 
IN FOLDER "\SCHEMAObjects\ATTRIBUTES\attrib1" 
HIDDEN FALSE ATTRIBUTEFORM "attrib1" FORMDESC "attrib1" 
FORMCATEGORY "ID" FORMTYPE NUMBER EXPRESSION "[attrib1]" 
EXPSOURCETABLES "attrib1_table" 
LOOKUPTABLE "attrib1_table" 
FOR PROJECT "Someproject";
```

Just looking for a version of this for CREATE REPORT.  Can't seem to find it on googles or in the documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately it's not possible to create a report using MicroStrategy Command Manager.

As you can see from the Outline window below (this shows all possible outlines in Command Manager with code samples) for you can list your reports, delete them or alter some properties of your MicroStrategy Reports.

[image: Command Manager Report Outlines]

As you can see from the outline for the ALTER REPORT command what you can modify is pretty limited, you can enable/disable cache, hide or un-hide a report, change the description or the long description, move a report to another folder.

If you want to create a report from scratch using code you need to use MicroStrategy SDK. You can start from this TechNote:
[TN38166: How to Create a Report and Filter Expression from Scratch Using the MicroStrategy Web SDK 9.2.x and 9.3.x.](https://community.microstrategy.com/t5/SDK/TN38166-How-to-Create-a-Report-and-Filter-Expression-from/ta-p/188342)